# Why is my for loop not registering the first line in its block?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, luhn

I have recently started learning the basics of coding from codeacademy and was given a project involving applying something called the "Luhn Algorithm" for validating credit card numbers. I think I understand the algorithm, but I seem to be getting something wrong in my JavaScript code.

```js
// I'm using this as a sample to test if it works
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];

// I used that Array for this piece of code:
const validateCred = arr => {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-=2) {
    for (let j = arr.length - 2; j >= 0; j-=2) {
      arr[j] *= 2;
      if (arr[j] > 9) {
        arr[j] -= 9;
      }
      const redFunc = (tot,num) => {
        return tot + num;
      }
      return total = arr.reduce(redFunc,0);
      
    }
  }
}
console.log(validateCred(invalid1));
```

And the answer that logs is 82. I checked the math manually and found out that it should be 85.

I figured out that the problem is that this code isn't registering

```
arr[j] *= 2;
```

I've been at it for hours but can't, for the life of me, figure out how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: I'm looking at Luhn algorithm online and it looks like your logic is wrong. There seems to be only one for loop. Also it says double every second digit, your code is counting backwards, which does not guarantee, you are not doubling the first digit.

Comment: I added a code example that I also tested on real credit cards and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[j] *= 2;` is registering.

Your logic have to be wrong. As you are a beginner, I recommend to try the *Quokka.js* extension for *VS Code* to troubleshoot your code and test it...

Like I did here:
[image]

```js
// Source for logic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

const validCreditCard1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 1, 4, 8, 8, 0, 3, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 7];
const invalidCreditCard1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const validAccountNumber1 = [7, 9, 9, 2, 7, 3, 9, 8, 7, 1, 3];
const invalidAccountNumber1 = [7, 9, 9, 2, 7, 3, 9, 8, 7, 1, 1];

/*
1. From the rightmost digit (excluding the check digit) and moving left,
   double the value of every second digit. The check digit is neither doubled nor included in this calculation;
   the first digit doubled is the digit located immediately left of the check digit. If the result of this doubling
   operation is greater than 9 (e.g., 8 × 2 = 16), then add the digits of the result (e.g., 16: 1 + 6 = 7, 18: 1 + 8 = 9) or,
   alternatively, the same final result can be found by subtracting 9 from that result (e.g., 16: 16 − 9 = 7, 18: 18 − 9 = 9).
2. Take the sum of all the digits.
3. If the total modulo 10 is equal to 0 (if the total ends in zero) then the number is valid
   according to the Luhn formula; otherwise it is not valid.

    *** Example: ***
    The sum of all the digits in the third row is 67+x.

    The check digit (x) is obtained by computing the sum of the non-check digits then computing 9 times
    that value modulo 10 (in equation form, ((67 × 9) mod 10)). In algorithm form:

    Compute the sum of the non-check digits (67).
    Multiply by 9 (603).
    The units digit (3) is the check digit. Thus, x=3.
*/

const checkLuhnIsValid = async (arrayDigits, isAccountNumberCheck) => {
    const arrayDigitsReversed = arrayDigits.slice().reverse();
    let totalSum = 0;
    // let checkDigitAccountNumber = null;

    await new Promise(resolve => {
        arrayDigitsReversed.map((digit, index, array) => {
            digit = Number(digit);

            if (digit) {
              // Check if digit needs to be subtracted with 9
              if (index % 2 === 1) { digit *= 2; if (digit > 9) { digit -= 9; } }
              // Add to the total sum
              totalSum += digit;
            }

            if ((index + 1) === array.length) {
                // Get the true check number of the total sum... (if 10 number account number + check number)
                // if (isAccountNumberCheck) { checkDigitAccountNumber = ((totalSum * 9) % 10); }

                resolve();
            }
        });
    });

    if (totalSum % 10 === 0) { return true; } else {
        return false;
    }
};

(async () => {
  console.log('validCreditCard1 isValid =>', await checkLuhnIsValid(validCreditCard1));
  console.log('invalidCreditCard1 isValid =>', await checkLuhnIsValid(invalidCreditCard1));
  console.log('validAccountNumber1 isValid =>', await checkLuhnIsValid(validAccountNumber1, true));
  console.log('invalidAccountNumber1 isValid =>', await checkLuhnIsValid(invalidAccountNumber1, true));
})();
```

```html
<p>
  Also tested on account number, VISA and MasterCard.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the implementations of the Luhn Algorithm online and I found a blog post that implements it: [Medium Post](https://medium.com/cyberdoggo/luhn-algorithm-in-javascript-python-clojure-part-1-c4ea3079d0f7)

It looks like your logic is little bit off, here is the implementation in the post:

```js
const isValid = card => {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      if (card[i]*2 < 10) {
        arr.push(card[i]*2);
      } else {
        arr.push(card[i]*2-9);
      }
    } else {
      arr.push(parseInt(card[i],10))
    }
  }
  return arr.reduce( (prv, cur) => prv + cur) % 10 === 0;
}
```

There seems to be only one for-loop. When I ran this code with your input with removing the last `%10 ===0`  part(I wanted it to return number instead of boolean) , I received *85*, which is your expected result.